# Run a command on cell-return in Jupyter Notebook/Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to make a visualization infrastructure I'm writing seamlessly compatible with Jupyter Notebook/Lab. The code I'm writing uses other jnote-compatible infrastructures such as Plotly & Bokeh.

What I want is to know if there's some interface/protocol that an object needs to implement in order for it to be used differently on return to the cell. For example, when a cell receives a HoloViews object (and has the appropriate plugin), it plots its consents.

What usually happens is that upon return to cell, the object's `__repr__` function is called, and the returned string is shown. I want that when my object is returned, it calls a function that interacts with the cell, such as ploting the plot interactively (again - suppose that the required plugins for plotting are already installed.).

Just to be clear, in my mind's eye it should look something like this:

```py
class JupyterViewable(IPythonInteractive):
    def get_interactive_object(self, kernel):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'This will not be viewed in the JNote!
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: Does the [Rich display](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#integrating-your-objects-with-ipython) section of IPython documentation answer your question? A lot depends on whether you are satisfied with IPython only, or want to support other kernels too (in which case it would be more complex and require widgets integration)

Comment: For now, IPython should be enough. Thanks! I'll take a look at it.